# How to change boolean false in a domain to boolean true in a controller

Tags: variables, grails, groovy, boolean

I have a domain class with a boolean variable "false". Now I want to change this boolean in my controller in a method to "true", how can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

**Domain:**

```
class Test {
 
  Boolean status = false

  static constraints = {
   
  }
}
```

**Controller method:**

```
def setTestDone(){
        def setTestDone = Test.get(params.id)
        try{
            setTestDone.status = true
        } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
            flash.error = runtimeException.message
        }
        redirect(controller:"test", action: "index")
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I added it above

Comment: How does the failure manifest?  Is the case that the execution flow is as expected but the status change is not being committed to the database?

Comment: The execution flow is as expected but the boolean status remains false and hasn't changed to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mrcreatesavestatus.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mrcreatesavestatus/blob/95ac4b7f2826b94746bc8825fc94dbaa6812ee66/grails-app/domain/mrcreatesavestatus/Test.groovy

```
package mrcreatesavestatus

class Test {
    Boolean status
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mrcreatesavestatus/blob/95ac4b7f2826b94746bc8825fc94dbaa6812ee66/grails-app/services/mrcreatesavestatus/TestService.groovy

```
package mrcreatesavestatus

import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(Test)
interface TestService {
    Test get(Serializable id)

    Test save(Boolean status)

    Test update(Serializable id, Boolean status)
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mrcreatesavestatus/blob/95ac4b7f2826b94746bc8825fc94dbaa6812ee66/grails-app/controllers/mrcreatesavestatus/TestController.groovy

```
package mrcreatesavestatus

class TestController {

    TestService testService

    def updateStatusTrue(Long id) {
        respond testService.update(id, true)
    }

    def updateStatusFalse(Long id) {
        respond testService.update(id, false)
    }

    def show(Long id) {
        respond testService.get(id)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mrcreatesavestatus/blob/95ac4b7f2826b94746bc8825fc94dbaa6812ee66/grails-app/init/mrcreatesavestatus/BootStrap.groovy

```
package mrcreatesavestatus

class BootStrap {

    TestService testService
    def init = { servletContext ->
        // save a Test instance with
        // status set to false
        testService.save false
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Those updates work well:

```
 $ http :8080/test/show/1.json
HTTP/1.1 200 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 13:22:50 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "id": 1,
    "status": false
}

 $ http :8080/test/updateStatusTrue/1.json
HTTP/1.1 200 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 13:23:02 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "id": 1,
    "status": true
}

 $ http :8080/test/updateStatusFalse/1.json
HTTP/1.1 200 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 13:23:09 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "id": 1,
    "status": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `save()` method to persist the changes to the DB:

```
 def setTestDone = Test.get params.id
 setTestDone.status = true
 if( !setTestDone.save() )
   println setTestDone.errors
```

See [ref-doc](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) for further info on additional options.

Comment: I added the save() method but nothing changed, also if I add setTestDone.save(flush: true) nothing happend

Comment: that means usually that your object does not pass the validation. see update

Answer (score 0):

If you are using grails try the following

**Domain**

```
class Test {
 
  boolean status // by default is false

  static constraints = {
   
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
def setTestDone(){
   def setTestDone = Test.get(params.id)
   setTestDone.status = true
   setTestDone.save(flush:true)
   redirect(controller:"test", action: "index")
}
```

The flush flag will call the transaction, immediately, but firs I suggest to have a service that makes this kind of work, the service layer is transactional by default so you can have something like this:

**Service**

```
@Transactional
class TestService {
     Test save(id){
        Test test = Test.get(id)
        test.status = true
        test.save(flush:true)
     }
}
```

And your controller should look like this:

**Controler**

```
class TestController {

  def testService // injected by convention

  def updateTest() {
     testService.save(params.id)
     redirect(controller:"test", action: "index")
  }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: If i try this i got a ecxeption: 
Class:        java.lang.NullPointerException
Message:   null
Caused by:  Cannot invoke method save() on null object